# How to extract value using Python?

Tags: python

I am wanting to extract the value in the YAML front matter of a document. Lets say the Front matter is the following:

```
---
Author: aaaa
Title: bbbb
...
```

I want to extract the value of "title:".

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25814568/is-it-possible-to-use-pyyaml-to-read-a-text-file-written-with-a-yaml-front-matt) Python is unable to parse YAML. So the following is the first part that i need as it only selects only the front matter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import yaml

def get_yaml(f):
  pointer = f.tell()
  if f.readline() != '---\n':
    f.seek(pointer)
    return ''
  readline = iter(f.readline, '')
  readline = iter(readline.next, '---\n')
  return ''.join(readline)
```

How do I now extract "Title:"??

Comment: You're importing the YAML package but never using it.

Answer (score 1):

You use `yaml.load(get_yaml(f))`, as proposed in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25816324/1743220) of the question you've linked. It returns a dictionary, so

```py
config = yaml.load(get_yaml(f))
print config.get('Title')
```